# Making a function accept vectors in R

Tags: r, vectorization

I have 36 files where each file contains data for one month for a certain year, so in total I have 36/12=3 years. Files from 1 to 12 are for year 2013, 13 to 24 for year 2012, and 25 to 36 for year 2011. I am trying to create a function that will take a year or years as an argument and return corresponding interval of file numbers. My attempt:

```
g<-function(year){
 lis<-vector()
 for( i in year){
  if(year==2013){lis<-append(lis,1:12)}
  if(year==2012){lis<-append(lis,13:24)}
  if(year==2011){lis<-append(lis,24:36)}
 }
return(lis)
}
```

With single years my function works fine. For example:

```
> g(2013)
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

I want the following output when I call `g(2013:2012)` or `g(2012:2013)`:

```
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

I thought `if` statements would do the trick, but it does not work. Let me know if you need any clarification. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your for loop, you don't actually use the individual values that you're looping through, you compare against the whole `year` vector every time. Using the individual values fixes your immediate problem:

```
g<-function(year){
  lis<-vector()
  for( i in year){
    if(i == 2013){lis<-append(lis,1:12)}
    if(i == 2012){lis<-append(lis,13:24)}
    if(i == 2011){lis<-append(lis,24:36)}
  }
  return(lis)
}
```

Or you could do the same thing without a for loop:

```
g2 <-function(year){
  lis<-vector()
  if (2013 %in% year) {lis <- append(lis, 1:12)}
  if (2012 %in% year) {lis <- append(lis, 13:24)}
  if (2011 %in% year) {lis <- append(lis, 24:36)}
  return(lis)
}
```

Comment: oh damn. A simple mistake on my part. Thanks.